# Add target="_blank" to Instagram Embed code

Tags: dictionary, embed, instagram

I made https://instmap.com/ and when user clicks on thumbnail on the map it shows popup with bigger embedded photo.

Problem is Instagram doesn't add `target="_blank"` so when user will click on the link, he will lost current map position and loaded photos.

Currently I disabled entire `div` with embedded code with `pointer-events: none` but it can be only temporary solution.

Any ideas to force all links in Instagram's embedded `iframe` to `target="_blank"`?

Comment: I don't think we can edit the content from iframe. Btw your site is nice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent them bug report and they fixed it, thanks!